# Stoll, Set Theory and Logic (pg 161): . Several other idioms .. same meaning as "If P, then Q"

Tags: math

```
Several other idioms in English which we shall regard as having the same meaning as "If P, then Q" (where P and Q are sentences):
P implies Q,
  P only if Q,
P is a sufficient condition for Q,
Q, provided that P,
Q if P,
  Q is a necessary condition for P.
```

How is "P only if Q" the same as "If P, then Q"?? That's like saying "implies" (=>) is the same meaning as "iff" (<=>).

I mean look at the direction: If P is true, then Q is also true. On the other hand:
P is true, only if Q is true - you are testing Q!! WTH?? From a compiler perspective: "P only if Q" would result in a test on Q??

Comment: Belongs to Math.stackexchange.com

Comment: It might involve the compiler

Answer (score 1):

All of those situations have the following in common:

1. If `P` is true, `Q` must also be true.
2. If `Q` is false, `P` must also be false.
3. If `P` is false, `Q` can be either true or false.
4. If `Q` is true, `P` can be either true or false.

Looking at the compiler perspective isn't useful.  This isn't pseudo-code.  This is a list of English language idioms which all produce the same logical result.  Moreover, `P only if Q` is probably terrible pseudo-code.  It usually works like this `if(Q){ P; }`, not `{ P; }if(Q)`...

Comment: Perl has: x if y; but even in English, "if Q then P" implies you are testing Q and not P. If (Jane was faithful), Harry would have stayed with her. Remember even in Math you have "if antecedent then consequent" aren't you interchanging the antecedent and consequent

Comment: Regardless of whether you're testing `P` or testing `Q`, the four statements I made in my answer are 100% correct.  I'm not familiar with the book the statement comes from, and the original post is out-of-context.  `P only if Q` has the same meaning as `If P, then Q` (the original statement) in somuchas if we KNOW `P` is true, then `Q` must be true.  If we KNOW `P` is false, `Q` can be true or false.  It doesn't matter what order you test in, the 4 scenarios are true.

Comment: hmm.. are you suggesting a 'truth table'?? The behavior of the "declarative sentence": P->Q  can be illustrated by a truth table and any other "declarative sentence" that generates a similar truth table must be equivalent. But a truth table has 3 expressions.. "P" "Q" and "P->Q" and you'll have P and Q taking T or F values - all possible combinations.